# Check if all spans with class "x" in a given div have an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check, with js or jquery, whether all `spans` with `class "x"` in a given `div` have the attribute `style="display: none"`.

I tried `$('div').find('.x').att('style', 'display: none')`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `.att()` doesn't exist, `.attr()` would set the value of the `style` attribute to `'display: none'`

Comment: Get all `<span>`s, compare the length of that collection with the length of result of a [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) call

Comment: Your attempt possibly could have been `$('div').find('.x').attr('style') == 'display: none'` - but if it had any other inline styles this would stop working (and there's no guarantee that it would be `display: none` or `display:none`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:hidden` selector to find `display="none"` elements and compare the length vs all `.x` elements

```
let allHidden = $('div').find('.x:hidden').length === $('div').find('.x').length
```

Comment: :hidden will include not just display:none but other elements too. But this might still work for the OP.

Comment: @TusharShahi on its own yes, but not combined with OPs original `.x` -> `.x:hidden`

Comment: well, not other elements since it will only be classname `x` but any `.x` that isnt visible

Comment: I mean, if `width and height are explicitly set to 0.` and the element has `class x` it will still be considered. But that is a corner case. [https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/]

Comment: Extra line, but collecting `.find(".x")` first then applying a filter would require only a single scan of the DOM.   Depends on how many `.x` there are if it's worth this optimisation, but always worth being wary of multiple scans.

Answer (score 0):

Along with `.hidden` count vs all count, you can check if there are any that are not hidden:

```
var allHidden = $('div').find('.x:not(:hidden)').length == 0
```

This may give a false positive if you don't have any at all.  It's up to you if "none" is the same as "all hidden" or if that's a case in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Attribute Selector.

```js
$(function() {
  var hidden = $("div > span.foo:hidden").length;
  var styleCount = $("div > span.foo[style*='display: none']").length;
  console.log(hidden, styleCount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="foo" style="display: none">I am hidden</span>
  <span class="foo">I am visible</span>
</div>
```

See More: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

You can use the `*=` to ensure that we can find `display: none` in the `style` attribute. You can use `=` for a direct comparison, yet this can fail if there are any other items in the style. Using the `*=` will allow it to be found in the following patterns:

```
style="display: none;"
style="display: none"
style="color: red; display: none;"
```

Comment: While this matches OPs requirement of `display: none`, it will depend on how that display:none gets there and if it's always *exactly* `display: none` - for example, using `$(".x").hide()` will set the style to `display :none;` https://jsfiddle.net/8zxr5k6g/ (at least in my current version of Chrome, other browsers may differ)

Comment: @freedomn-m agree, it's not the best solution, just another option. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the simplest answer for you.

```
var hiddenItems = $("div").find('span.x:hidden');

console.log(hiddenItems);
alert("Check the results in the console.");
```